# How to I find project/repo/pipeline level activity log in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to find a way to view the changes at project structural level.

Eg: Who created/edited/deleted the repo or project or pipeline excluding the details like commits/build details etc. Idea is to identify the person who messes up the system.

Thank You in advance. :)

**Couldn't spot anything on azure portal activity log.

Comment: Allowing all your users to have Project Administrator rights is not a good idea. You should really take the time to set up the security to ONLY allow developers (and other roles) access to privileges they NEED on the day-to-day. Then when they need to do something for which their role is insufficient, you can have the explicit conversation about granting that access.

Comment: Yeah, team is working on a POC & permissions will get revoked as soon as its done. But we need a dashboard to track project level changes during this period. I couldn't find any good extension/in built functionality. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Auditing** in the organization Settings can meet your needs.
[image]

When an auditable event occurs, a log entry is recorded. These events may occur in any portion of Azure DevOps; some examples of auditable events include: Git repository creations, permission changes, resource deletions, code downloads, accessing the auditing feature, and much more.

For details, you can refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/auditing-for-azure-devops-is-now-in-public-preview/) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops). Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like this is it. Will test it out n let u know. Thank you. :)